# how to overwrite cy.request and log response body to file for all requests in all tests?

Tags: request, cypress

Cypress version 13.2.0.

I need to collect all requests that my e2e tests are doing via `cy.request(...)` for further analysis in a pipeline.

- I've checked existing plugin [cypress-har-generator](https://github.com/NeuraLegion/cypress-har-generator) but unfortunately, it only intercepts requests from the browser, but not from nodejs where `cy.request` is executed.
- I've checked `cy.intercept`, but it is designed to intercept requests that the app is doing, not requests made by `cy.request`.

I ended up with something like this in my `e2e.ts` file:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite("request", (originalFn, ...options) => {
  return originalFn(...options).then(response => {
    try {
      cy.writeFile('requests.log', `${JSON.stringify({ options,  response })}\n`, {flag: 'a+'});
      // I think I need this line to yield the original value
      // but it fails with same error anyway
      // cy.wrap(response);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  })
});
```

it fails with error

```js
CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise 
from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands 
in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

  > `cy.request()`

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

  > `cy.writeFile()`

Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, 
you don't need to wrap them or return your own promise.
```

Another try without return as error message suggests:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite("request", (originalFn, ...options) => {
  originalFn(...options).then(response => {
    try {
      cy.writeFile('requests.log', `${JSON.stringify({ options,  response })}\n`, {flag: 'a+'});
      // samve error with and without 
      cy.wrap(response)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
  })
});
```

And error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
```

This is kind of expected because I did not return value, but my tests use it.

So how I intercept the request in the right way?

Comment: Did you look at documentation? https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To intercept response of cypress command you have to store the return value under a temporary alias, then perform your side effects and yield the aliased value:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite("request", (originalFn, ...options) => {
  // using prefix __ to reduce chance of collision with user defined aliases
  cy.wrap(originalFn(...options)).as("__intercepted_response")

  cy.get("@__intercepted_response").then((response) => {
    cy.writeFile('requests.log', `${JSON.stringify({options, response})}\n`, {flag: 'a+'})
  })

  return cy.get("@__intercepted_response");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can emit an event from the overwritten `cy.request()` to avoid nesting command execution within another command's handler.

Nesting commands breaks the queue mechanism, which is why Cypress throws the error `Cypress detected that you returned a promise  from a command...`.

Using the event system means the log is not written immediately, but that doesn't matter since you only want to produce an artifact.

But I'm not sure about the effect when there are multiple overlapping requests, you would have to see if that breaks this solution.

```js
Cypress.on('custom:log:request', ({options, response}) => {
  try {
    cy.writeFile('requests.log', `${JSON.stringify({ options,  response })}\n`, {flag: 'a+'});
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
})

Cypress.Commands.overwrite("request", (originalFn, ...options) => {
  return originalFn(...options).then(response => {
    Cypress.emit('custom:log:request', {options, response})  // must pass a single object
    return response
  })
})

it('test request overwrite', () => {
  cy.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .its('status')
    .should('eq', 200)
})
```

---

#### Burn testing

Seems to work ok over a number of requests.

```js
Cypress._.times(10, (index) => {
  cy.request(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${index+1}`)
    .its('status')
    .should('eq', 200)
})
```

Comment: It worked for several sequential tests, but started failing with `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')` after several successful responses. I did not troubleshoot it well before finding another solution (see my answer), so I can not say what exactly is wrong here.

Comment: Not entirely sure that is caused by this, so I did a burn test on my method and it seems to hold up ok.

Comment: You were getting that error previously, perhaps add `failOnStatusCode: false` and check out the request/response.